# Self-hosted Roboto font is not being rendered

Tags: html, css

I have setup a website with GitHub Pages using Jekyll and I host the stylesheet for the Roboto font (using Google would increase page load time). I then import it in my html as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='{{ site.baseurl }}/static/css/roboto.css'>
```

site.baseurl is an empty string, so no issues with it.

In my CSS file, I use

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

but it doesn't work. The font is not being rendered on screen. What is happening and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I realized the font files I was hosting didn't include the Roboto font. I downloaded the correct files and replaced them, and now it works like a charm.